# Connecting an android app to my local server

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am new in Android and I just got some tutorial on how to use it and sqlLite.

The problem:

I have a MySQL server on my local PC and I am using Android studio to develop my Android application. My application will have a listing of pharmacies in my database, and the pharmacies are in the server database.

How can I connect to MySQL from Android to my local PC and get the pharmacies' details from the database?

I created a Java class for the pharmacies in my application and an http request function to get the list from the database and return a json object, but I couldn't connect to the local database. Should I put the connection string as the IP of my PC?

Can someone provide a tutorial for me? I couldn't find a replica of my problem on the internet.

Comment: Well, have you tried using your computer's private IP? Are both devices on the same network? If not you'll need to port forward and use your public IP.

Answer (score 3):

To connect your android app to your local server, your base url has to be the ip of the computer with the local server eg.

```
String baseUrl = "http://192.0.2.120:8080"; //Java

              //or

val baseUrl :String = "http://192.0.2.120:8080" //Kotlin
```

The baseUrl is passed into your retrofit or whatever http client you are using

Please note that the android device and the local machine should be connected to the same network.

Answer (score -1):

Try this!!!

```
localhost/yournamefile/.....
```

Or see tutorial

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Hope. It will help you !!!!